# http is being changed to https for https://www.youtube.com in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I noticed strange behaviour in Chrome when I access the Youtube resources. If my page references any YT resource e.g. http://www.youtube.com/embed/M5qkVGna18s I see the response 301 and redirect to https. This issue occurs only in chrome and introduce some bugs.

Is it possible to avoid switching to HTTPS in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The only time Chrome will always redirect is if you set it to, a lot of sites where important information is transmitted will force HTTPS, why in the world would you not want to use HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience this can be the case with your browser cache, you have to clear it then try after logout from your google acount.

Comment: @user2699355 please vote if this answer worked for you, so it will be helpful for others as well